# Replace values in a nested list with values of another nested list based on a condition

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
l = [
     ['0.064', 'facebook', '0'],  
     ['0.019', 'twitt', '0'], 
     ['0.018', 'netzwerk', '0'], 
     ['0.016', 'nachricht', '0'], 
     ['0.015', 'youtub', '0']
     ]
```

```
fl = [
     ['twitter', 'twitt', 1], 
     ['youtube', 'youtub', 2], 
     ['nachrichten', 'nachricht', 4]
     ]
```

As you can see the entries at index `[1]` in list `l` are stems, which I want to replace with values from list `fl`.

So if both entries at index `[1]` in list `l` and `fl` then I want to replace the entry at index `[1]` in `l` with the entry at index `[0]` in `fl`.

Expected result:

```
keys = [
     ['0.064', 'facebook', '0'],  
     ['0.019', 'twitter', '0'], 
     ['0.018', 'netzwerk', '0'], 
     ['0.016', 'nachrichten', '0'], 
     ['0.015', 'youtube', '0']
     ]
```

I tried something like this:

```
keys =[]
for l in l:
    for i in fl:
        if l[1] == i[1]:
            i[1].replace(i[1], l[0])
            keys.append(i)
```

But this does not work.

Can somebody help?

Comment: You are having a wrong data structure to start with.

Comment: What is the relevance of third element in each of the sublists in `fl`?

Comment: Hey Austin, they are word counts I used for a groupby statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second list is better transformed to a dictionary and make use of `O(1)` lookup:

```
l = [
     ['0.064', 'facebook', '0'],  
     ['0.019', 'twitt', '0'], 
     ['0.018', 'netzwerk', '0'], 
     ['0.016', 'nachricht', '0'], 
     ['0.015', 'youtub', '0']
]

fl = [
     ['twitter', 'twitt', 1], 
     ['youtube', 'youtub', 2], 
     ['nachrichten', 'nachricht', 4]
]

d = dict((x[1], x[0]) for x in fl)
keys = [[x[0], d.get(x[1], x[1]), x[2]] for x in l]

print(keys)
```